# Removing html tags without breaking lines with php

Tags: php

I'm using an api and I need to get the description of product registrations from a certain store. But the product registration comes in html format and the api does not accept HTML. I've used strip_tags from php to remove the html tags, but it does not keep the line breaks of the text (). Is there any way to do something like this?

```
  $description = ($product->description != "") ? strip_tags($product->description) : trim($product->name);
  $description = nl2br($product->description);
```

Comment: Are you sure the line breaks are line breaks and not HTML line breaks (`<br />`)?

Comment: @LourençonO. you can now (safely) delete all of your above comments. I will delete this one shortly when I've seen yours deleted.

Comment: btw, you have posted what seems to be the same question here https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246571 - I feel that only one post is enough.

Comment: @LourençonO. please don't post comments in Portuguese; this area is in English only. Either delete the question and continue with your other one here https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246571 edit: I see you deleted that comment now.

Comment: Yes, a description of the product comes with a tag, however I tried to remove it with strip_tags from php, so it leaves an inline string

Comment: Please post code that we can reproduce the issue (e.g. defined strings) with. `nl2br` is called on the original string, not the stripped version. Which variable are you using?

Comment: exemple: "<p>PLACA PRINCIPAL TV LED SAMSUNG UN58H5203AG<br />UN58H5203AGXZD<br />VERS: 1013.1<br />BN91-13444M<br />SEMI NOVA OK</p>"